# C fread() and buffer management

Tags: c, optimization, io, fread, stdio

Let's suppose I am parsing a file of binary records.  The file could contain any number of records.  The format is:

- 12 bytes C-string
- 4 bytes length
- 4 bytes offset

I intend to use `fread()` to get records from the file, and transform them into an internal data structure.  As I understand it, `fread()` has its own internal buffer over the data file, to cut down on hard disk access for small reads.

So there are two options:

- Loop: Read 20 bytes at a time with `fread()` and parse it.  This is easy, but has the drawback that I'm making a function call to `fread()` in every loop.  It's not as bad as a syscall, but it still incurs the overhead every 20 bytes.  In an extreme alternative case (say, one-byte-at-a-time file decompression) I could be doing a function call *every byte*.
- Read a big block at a time with `fread()`, then Loop: traverse my copy 20 bytes at a time, and parse it.  Parsing local memory is fast, but this has the drawback that I'm "buffering a buffer" - that is, filling the internal `fread()` buffer, just so I can turn around and `memcpy()` it to another structure.  Also, it's kind of tedious - either I have to fit the whole file in RAM myself, or I have to manage my own buffer-fill-and-flush routine to read the file in chunks.

So I'm in a bit of a bind here, because neither solution seems theoretically optimal!

My question is: **Is there any pattern for using sequential file IO that avoids *both* of these drawbacks?**  (And please, no "just profile it" comments - the question is not "which of these is better" but "is there a third alternative")

Comment: The "third alternative" is OS-dependent, e.g. `mmap()` on a POSIX system. If you want to stick to C stdio, just use the simple approach and let stdio handle the buffering.

Comment: Quote: `no "just profile it" comments` Why not? It's likely you are "inventing" a problem that isn't real. You might find that any thing you do in SW is irrelevant compared to disk access time. Guessing about performance is nearly impossible in modern systems.

Comment: Because the question is about a software design pattern.

Comment: @GregKennedy I don't read this a a design pattern issues. I read it as a performance issue.

Comment: The fourth alternative is to use `read` and manage your own buffers.

Comment: @melpomene which is OS-dependent as well (I guess you mean the POSIX function `read()`)

Comment: If your platform supports async IO you can look into that too. It's more complex but may give you improved performance.

Comment: @melpomene After some more searching, I find this: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Controlling-Buffering.html
It looks like with POSIX I can use `read()` in combination with my own buffer of size `BUFSIZ` (or `fstat()` -> `st_blksize`), to basically implement `fread()` in my own program.  Which does give me the desired combination of "a single buffer" and "a low function call overhead".  Of course, I still have to manage chunking myself.

Comment: Read about setvbuf and _IONBF, then just use fread.

Comment: Be aware that the underlying file operations might buffer even if you don't, and this may even be handled by the operating system. The operating system certainly isn't touching the disk and reading 20 bytes and 20 bytes only. Your best option is to profile and measure where you have a bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

> So I'm in a bit of a bind here, because neither solution seems theoretically optimal!

and

> And please, no "just profile it" comments - the question is not "which of these is better" but "is there a third alternative")

Well, most systems has alternatives to `fread`. For instance memory mapped files, async IO, `read()`. Further, there are typically a number of ways to "configure" the different types of file access, e.g. for memory mapped files you can choose to populate the whole file file.

However, there is no single method that can be considered the **better** solution. No matter which method you go for, you'll end up with:

**just profile it**

For method 1 you write:

> This is easy, but has the drawback that I'm making a function call to fread() in every loop.

This together with "seems theoretically optimal" is the key here. You are making assumptions without proofs. You can't just judge performance by saying "it seems".

Guessing about performance solely by looking at the C-code is nearly impossible on modern computer systems where extreme optimizations happens both during compilation and execution.

How do you know that a `fread` call for every 20 bytes is a problem compared to the disk access which is really slow?

Again, it brings you back to:

**just profile it**

Just for fun I made some simple benchmarks on my Linux box using `fread` with different numbers of nmemb. The program read a 1G file and calculated a simple running sum using 1 byte in every block read.

**Results when file is cold (i.e. not cached)**

```
nmemb        time (sec)
   1             15.68
   2             15.76
   4             15.91
   8             15.93
  20             15.60
1000             15.60
```

**Results when file is hot (i.e. cached)**

```
nmemb        time (sec)
   1            13.90
   2             7.04
   4             3.79
   8             2.07
  20             1.09
1000             0.42
```

So on my system the block size (nmemb) doesn't matter when the file is cold. For most application I would consider a cold file "the normal case" but for sure there are applications that may read the same file several times.

If the file is hot (i.e. cached due to previous reads) the block size matters. But the difference rapidly decrease as the block size increase. Already at 20 versus 1000 the difference is pretty small.

From the above I would conclude: Just read 20 bytes each time to keep the code simple.

All the above measurements/conclusions are valid **only** for my specific system. Another system may generate completely different results depending on type/speed of CPU and disk system and OS.

So once again, it brings us back to:

**just profile it**